# enter stomp command using telnet

Tags: terminal, telnet, stomp

I am trying to enter the following command in Mac terminal using telnet, however it does not return anything. Which keyboard combination should I use in order to enter the command?( I used ^D ^V ^M, they did not work )

```
CONNECT
login: admin
passcode: password
```

Comment: For linux, just press CTRL-SHIFT-2 together

Answer (score 2):

From the [STOMP spec](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.0.html):

```
CONNECT
login: <username>
passcode:<passcode>

^@
```

> The ^@ is a null (control-@ in ASCII) byte. The entire thing will be
>   called a Frame in this doc. The frame starts with a command (in this
>   case CONNECT), followed by a newline, followed by headers in a
>   : with each header followed by a newline. A blank line
>   indicates the end of the headers and beginning of the body (the body
>   is empty in this case), and the null indicates the end of the frame.

To enter the nullbyte ^@ on a Mac OSX terminal:

- Press control+@
- Type control+v and then control+m

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. 
After typing the command, leave 1 line blank and then on the next line enter kntrl+v kntrl+m